# How to merge groups of UIAnnotationView?

Tags: mapkit, mkannotationview, mapquest

I need to merge groups of MKAnnotationView (MQAnnotationView) like it is in Places of Photos app. How to do it? Is there any free solutions?

Comment: Do you mean put multiple piece of data at the same point and have just one annotation for them? That's called clustering, and has been asked a few times on hear. Try searching for that term.

Comment: Yes, clustering. The problem is there is no free solutions as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are approaches for this on MapKit, or you could use the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk), which does this natively. More at http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/examples/marker-clustering/